# Cannot run /bin/mount on NFS share with root_squash enabled

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I have a NFS share mounted on /.

```
/srv/nfs/gentoo/i686-gentoo  192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(all_squash,ro,no_subtree_check)
```

Running mount with any "squash" option will prevent the client from running /bin/mount.

```
bash: /bin/mount: Permission denied
```

I can mount filesystems, but running mount with no arguments results in "Permission denied".  This is causing problems with systemd and is interfering with the boot process.  I have to manually mount whatever options that are in the fstab file and resume the boot process.

If I specify no_root_squash, then /bin/mount runs fine.  How do I "squash" the NFS share while being able to run /bin/mount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Gentoo's `/bin/mount` is `-rws--x--x` by default. Changing it to `-rwsr-xr-x` fixed the problem.